# Change value of all date fields in .tab file using batch script

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have a .tab<tab separated file> which has many date fields.

My requirement is to process this file using batch processing in windows such that all the values in date fields are incremented by 1 year. And save the output file <containing normal fields and modified date fields>.

The date fields are in no proper order, hence they need to be searched among the file using the format. The following formats have been used:

```
11/11/2011 
4 years ago
34 months ago
547 days ago
```

For example:

```
Id         date1             date2
1        11/11/2011        3 years ago
2        46 months ago     567 days ago
```

The above after processing the output file should look like

```
Id        date1              date2
1        11/11/2012        2 years ago
2        34 months ago     202 days ago


 The data above is formatted for the sake of understanding.. the actual tab delimited file looks like:
```

Id  date1   date2
1   11/11/2011  3 years ago
2   46 months ago   567 days ago

Update: Unfortunately, the above also looks weird when pasting here (without any newline), any option to attach the file here??

OK.. Thanks to Magoo for giving the idea.. here is the link to drive containing the file

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9XC4xcTUoq1OEZsODZFaTl6aDQ/edit?usp=sharing

However, the sample file has been created like this:

Iddate1date2111/11/20113 years ago246 months ago<567 days ago>

I tried to find it on the internet, but no luck. Writing here, expecting that someone could help me.

UPDATE:

Magoo's solution works but not getting exact O/P

Notable is the input is tab delim (which I couldn't correctly paste here because of formatting issues) also the O/P should come as Tab Delim.

Here is what I am getting with the code.

```
Id  date1   date2      
1   11/11/2012   1  11/11/2013   1  11/11/2014
2 days ago
```

Also, this is a sample file, the actual file contains mixture of 50 date and non date columns (column position are fixed), so it would be great if we can dynamically (not sure but may be we could search for the above formats) find the date fields and change the date values.

Comment: If you post some of the file in question then it would be clearer.  I'm not sure if your file actually contains "`3 years ago`" because an example should show what the file **actually looks like**.

Comment: Hi, the file actually looks like this having different formats to define a date "x years ago" is one of the format :)

Comment: You need to clarify your input format. You describe the data as `tab-delimited` but the data you have posted has no tabs. Is the file actually fixed-column? Is the header offset (by 2 chars for col>1 on input;1, then 2 on output)? I replaced the space-sequence you had posted with `TABS` as you'd described. Small changes would need to be made if the fields are actually fixed-column. I get exactly the same output as you report if the input file is fixed-column and doesn't include the tabs you describe - and you omitted to report the "Missing Operator." message.

Comment: @ OP.  Are you asking us to believe that your input file looks like that.  What program is using data in that exact format?  You have to understand that with poor source files you will in all likelihood get code that doesn't work on a real file.

Comment: Magoo: I am extremely sorry for any confusion.. The file is exactly Tab-delim.. I updated the question with exactly pasting from the sample file to here without any modification....

Comment: foxidive: Believe me the file does contains fields like this.. the file is used in C#.. Please don't ask me why the file has such weird fields representation.. :)

Comment: I'd post your data to dropbox and paste a link here if I was you. Will have to change the approach if the data has 50 columns. Make sure you disguise any sensitive data and really - only a few representative rows required.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9XC4xcTUoq1OEZsODZFaTl6aDQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @magoo When people refuse to give you an accurate picture of their data, I find that it ends in frustration when you try to help.  I don't know how you feel about the matter but after the 900th time you have to draw a line and just ask for real data.  If you do create some code, it's so often bound to fail and then there is back and forth dialog trying to figure out what is really in the source file.  If it's really simple then offer some code, sure, but...

Comment: @foxidrive: Hey.. I am really sorry for any trouble you faced.. I had no idea how to provide tab delim data here till Magoo suggested to upload it on dropbox.. dropbox was down so I uploaded it to google drive.. I had spent hours in solving other's problem on stackoverflow on the areas I had any knowledge.. Now the same help I was expecting from others... Any code which process the file uploaded to drive and produce the desired O/P is welcomed...  If any more info is needed please let me know..!!

Comment: @foxidrive If you look at the edit history, you'll see that OP has made many attempts to provide this data. Not easy when dealing with whitespace and autoformatting unfortunately. Now had we been thinking, we'd have posted this as `#`-delimited with a note that `#` is actually `tab` to make it easier to distinguish tabs and spaces. Better than my experience in my last job, where a silly witch of a degree-waving "colleague" insisted on calling a fixed-column format file "tab-delimiNATED`.

Comment: @magoo Do you think that the file on google drive is representative of the real data that the OP wants to process?

Comment: @foxidrive probably not. It's actually the precise data I used in the testing of the original version. Strange that OP then tested it against fixed-column space-filled data. But who knows? Perhaps the real data is at "work" (whatever that is) but the format is imprinted on OP's consciousness...

Comment: @Magoo: Here is how I proceed. I took your code and run it against "input.tab" file uploaded in drive. I got empty file. Then I just changed the extension of input file to "input.txt" https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9XC4xcTUoq1WXp4NVRta0d0WW8/edit?usp=sharing and then process it with your code, here is what I got :     https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9XC4xcTUoq1MmpYdlE5RUNSeGs/edit?usp=sharing    .I am not sure where the things are going wrong

Comment: Have you seen the new version I've posted? You'd need to change `q20151778.txt` to your input filename. If I use your `input.txt` file which does **not** contain tabs, I get garbage out to `newfile.txt` If I use your posted `input.tab`, then `newfile.txt` contains the massaged data with tab-separators.

Comment: I have tried using your edited code <saved it as .bat file> with input.tab. The O/P does contain tab delim values but the values are not correct. see https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9XC4xcTUoq1ZnFsMlgwa2xoM0k/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: The character between the = and closing quote in the next line is a TAB
SET "tab=   "
(
 FOR /f "tokens=1-3delims=%tab%" %%a IN (q21051778.txt) DO (
  SET "line="
  SET "column=%%a"&CALL :process
  SET "column=%%b"&CALL :process
  SET "column=%%c"&CALL :process Y
 )
)>newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF

:process
FOR %%A IN (Field1 Field2 Field3) DO SET "%%R="
:: Format 1 : num/num/num - possibly with leading 0s
FOR /f "tokens=1,2*delims=/" %%A IN ("%column%") DO (
 SET field1=%%A
 SET field2=%%B
 SET field3=%%C
)
IF DEFINED field3 CALL :plaindate
SET "endtext= years ago"
CALL :adjust 10 1
SET "endtext= months ago"
CALL :adjust 11 12
SET "endtext= days ago"
CALL :adjust 9 365
IF "%1"=="Y" (ECHO %line%%tab%%column%
 ) ELSE (
 IF DEFINED line (SET "line=%line%%tab%%column%") else (set "line=%column%")
)
GOTO :eof

GOTO :eof

:: If the last %1 characters of column are %endtext% and the remainder is numeric,
:: subtract %2 from the numeric part
:adjust
CALL SET "endpart=%%column:~-%1%%"
IF /i NOT "%endpart%"=="%endtext%" GOTO :EOF 
CALL SET "endpart=%%column:~0,-%1%%"
CALL :isnumeric %endpart%
IF %numeric%==N GOTO :eof
SET /a endpart=%endpart%-%2
CALL SET "column=%endpart%%%column:~-%1%%"
GOTO :eof

:plaindate
CALL :isnumeric %field1%
IF %numeric%==N GOTO :eof
CALL :isnumeric %field2%
IF %numeric%==N GOTO :eof
CALL :isnumeric %field3%
IF %numeric%==N GOTO :eof
SET /a field3+=1
:: Reconstruct with modified contents
SET column=%field1%/%field2%/%field3%
GOTO :eof

:: Check whether %1 is purely numeric.
:: set 'numeric'=Y or N
:isnumeric
:: Include a leading "9" which will be removed IN the final FOR iteration
SET "numeric=9%1"
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /l %%n IN (0,1,9) DO SET numeric=!numeric:%%n=!
endlocal&SET "numeric=%numeric%"
IF DEFINED numeric (SET numeric=N) ELSE (SET numeric=Y)
GOTO :eof
```

Processed as you asked.

It's not possible to update the file in-place. A new file has to be created. I've called the original file `q21051778.txt` and the new file `newfile.txt`. You'd need to change those to suit yourself.

You could replace the original file  by executing

```
move /y newfile.txt q21051778.txt
```

but you should only do this after testing and verification.

If you need more columns, it's just a matter of changing the `3` in `tokens=1-3` to your max # and adding more  `SET "column=..."&CALL :process` lines, changing the selected column by incrementing the letter. Only the very last `call :process` shot have a `Y` parameter (this is what triggers a line of output)

---

Revision given new parameters. This version should be immune to column-limits but relies heavily on the presence of `tab` characters as described.

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: The character between the = and closing quote in the next line is a TAB
SET "tab=   "
(
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q21051778.txt) DO (
  SET "line="
  SET "lineread=%%a"
  CALL :process
 )
)>newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF

:process
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=%tab%" %%b IN ("%lineread%") DO (SET "column=%%b"&SET "lineread=%%c")
FOR %%A IN (Field1 Field2 Field3) DO SET "%%R="
:: Format 1 : num/num/num - possibly with leading 0s
FOR /f "tokens=1,2*delims=/" %%A IN ("%column%") DO (
 SET field1=%%A
 SET field2=%%B
 SET field3=%%C
)
IF DEFINED field3 CALL :plaindate
SET "endtext= years ago"
CALL :adjust 10 1
SET "endtext= months ago"
CALL :adjust 11 12
SET "endtext= days ago"
CALL :adjust 9 365
IF DEFINED line (SET "line=%line%%tab%%column%") else (set "line=%column%")
IF DEFINED lineread GOTO process
ECHO %line%
GOTO :eof

:: If the last %1 characters of column are %endtext% and the remainder is numeric,
:: subtract %2 from the numeric part
:adjust
CALL SET "endpart=%%column:~-%1%%"
IF /i NOT "%endpart%"=="%endtext%" GOTO :EOF 
CALL SET "endpart=%%column:~0,-%1%%"
CALL :isnumeric %endpart%
IF %numeric%==N GOTO :eof
SET /a endpart=%endpart%-%2
CALL SET "column=%endpart%%%column:~-%1%%"
GOTO :eof

:plaindate
CALL :isnumeric %field1%
IF %numeric%==N GOTO :eof
CALL :isnumeric %field2%
IF %numeric%==N GOTO :eof
CALL :isnumeric %field3%
IF %numeric%==N GOTO :eof
SET /a field3+=1
:: Reconstruct with modified contents
SET column=%field1%/%field2%/%field3%
GOTO :eof

:: Check whether %1 is purely numeric.
:: set 'numeric'=Y or N
:isnumeric
:: Include a leading "9" which will be removed IN the final FOR iteration
SET "numeric=9%1"
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /l %%n IN (0,1,9) DO SET numeric=!numeric:%%n=!
endlocal&SET "numeric=%numeric%"
IF DEFINED numeric (SET numeric=N) ELSE (SET numeric=Y)
GOTO :eof
```

Comment: That work good only issue is I am not getting desired O/P.. (+1 for the good code).. Please see the update in question..  I am trying to modify the code a bit to get I want.. but not sure how much I'll succeed.

Answer (score 2):

The Batch file below assume that the position of the data in the file is fixed, so it just take the years from the appropriate columns. If the date position may change, a more complex solution is needed.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "line="
for /F "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do (
   if not defined line (
      set "line=%%a"
      echo !line!
   ) else (
      set "line=%%a"
      set /A y1=!line:~15,2!+1, y2=!line:~28,2!+1
      echo !line:~0,15!!y1!!line:~17,11!!y2!
   )
)
```

Comment: nice. But I'm afraid "which have many date fields" means date3, date4, date5, ...

Comment: great there are multiple date fields.. the file is <.tab> extension. Can we make use of that?? Also.. is there any way to dynamically find date fields looking the format??

Comment: Also, the script should modify the input file..!!